# File not downloaded when Response.End() is replaced by ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

Tags: asp.net, download, threadabortexception

I would like to create a file download. Here is the original code for it:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=""Dashboard_{0}.html""", time))
Response.Write(html)
Response.End()
```

It looked okay. File was downloaded normally, but I found the below message in Output.

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I have tried to search for solutions of how to fix this exception, and I saw everyone talking about replacing `Response.End()` with `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`.

When I tried it, the exception no longer occurred, but the outcome was even worse - file not downloaded after the change. It was same as if I just remove `Response.End()` and add nothing.

In such case, what should I do to get rid of the exception when downloading needs to occur? Or should I just ignore the exception since it does not seem to create any unfavourable outcome?

Answer (score -1):

Here response.End()

> To mimic the behavior of the End method in ASP, this method tries to
>   raise a [ThreadAbortException] exception.

Please take a look at this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.end?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpResponse_End

also try removing

> Response.Clear()